# Can i trigger a javascript function when another user updates a table in mysql, without using a setInterval() function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Helo,

Right now iam using a setinterval function to check every 200ms if there is a change in the mysql database to make sure a playlist in html and javascript is still up to date in order and songs.

As soon as a user changes the order, or adds a song or removes a song from the playlist table in mysql, i want a javascript function to run ONLY when a change is made and not ping my server 5 times per second.

Right now i use this code:

```
setInterval(function() {

    contact();

},200)
```

where contact is like this

```
function contact() {
      getPlaylist()
      getInstructions();
      setStatus();

}


function getInstructions() {

    var url = BU+'player/instructions';
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        for(var i in data) {
            execute(data[i]);
        }
    });
}
function execute(instruction) {

    switch(instruction.Name) {

        case 'Next':
            nextSong();
            break;
        case 'PP':
            togglePlay();
            break;
        case 'Back':
            back();
            break;
        case 'Seek':
            setProgress(parseFloat(instruction.Value));
            break;
        case 'Setpsong':
            setPlaylistsong(parseFloat(instruction.Value));
            break;
    }


}




function getPlaylist(edit,force) {
    if(typeof(force) == 'undefined') {
        force = false;
    }
    var url = BU+'player/playlist';
    var res = false;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {

            if(force || typeof($('.playlistitems').attr('data')) == 'undefined' || (new Date(data.timestamp) > new Date($('.playlistitems').attr('data')))) {

                res = renderPlaylist(data,edit);

            }
        },

    }).fail(function() {

        if( $('.playlistitems .song').length > 0) {
            $('.playlistitems').html('');
        }
    });

    return res;
}
```

As you can see this will be a lot of traffic if there are 100 users using this program. I really want to use a method that ONLY triggers when a change is made, instead of checking 5 times per second IF a change is made.

Is this possible?

Comment: the best way is to open a socket connection between your client and server. this way you can always listen to server changes.

Comment: Best bet is to look into websockets, or longpolling ajax.

Comment: Why don't you query the change only after it happens, or hold sort of a state what has changed on frontend, without ever asking the DB. This is the pattern you should be looking, unless other users can influence playlists of you as a user for example.

Comment: i have a playlist that every user can change by adding songs or changing their songs i want it to synch with every other use, for reference it is a karaoke request script, so people are able to request a song to sing at a karaoke without bothering the barhead.

Answer (score -2):

Yes Possible When ever user perform operation on database like add, edit, Delete there will be a callback function invoke.